# Angular: ng-click parameter is undefined, which is inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I came across a problem when I try to pass param from ng-click to my function. I couldn't get my param. I am a new learner of Angular.js. So I think I may lack of basic understanding for ng-click inside ng-repeat. If anyone can help, I will be really appreciate it. Thank you.

View:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="recipe in urCtrl.userRecipes | filter: {category: 'Grill'}">
    <td>{{ recipe.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ recipe.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ recipe.category}}</td>
    <td>{{ recipe.ingredients }}</td>
    <td>{{ recipe.instructions }}</td>
    <button ng-click="deleteRecipe(recipe.id)">Delete</button>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
(function userRecipeControllerIIFE() {

var UserRecipeController = function($scope, likeRecipesFactory, recipesFactory, appSettings) {

    function init() {

        ....

      $scope.deleteRecipe = function(data){
        console.log("this is recipe: ", data);
      };
    };

    init();
};

UserRecipeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'likeRecipesFactory', 'recipesFactory', 'appSettings'];

angular.module('recipesApp').controller('userRecipeController', UserRecipeController);
})();
```

Route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/user', {
            controller: 'userRecipeController as urCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/urView.html'
        })
```

Console:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46OuM.png)

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for everyone's help. I am so new to developer's world, so it took me some time to learn JSfiddle and put my codes in there. Even though I add angular for external resource and also add angular for framework, I still couldn't let it work. But I still put fiddle here, if anyone think it's helpful. I modified my origin code a little bit.

JSfiddle[1](https://jsfiddle.net/tina_l/03gvnqnh/10/)

Comment: Can you show the whole controller as well as the tag you attached the controller to? From what it looks like, you're using `controller as` some of the time, and not other times.

Comment: are you sure `id` field is populated? try to pass the entire object `deleteRecipe(recipe)` see if you get anything. Also - what's the point of using `vm` and `$scope`?

Comment: I have update the whole controller as you suggested. Thank you@Ted

Comment: The id for each recipe has populated. I changed param from recipe.id to recipe as you suggested, and I still get undefined. Thank you@Muli Yulzary

Comment: @tina could you please create a plunkr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `urCtrl.deleteRecipe(recipe.id)` since you are using `controller as` and hence every time you refer to anything in your controller, you need to use the variable name you decided to use.

Take a look [here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) for all the syntax details of `controller as`

**UPDATE:**

Ok, thanks for the JSFiddle! Just what we needed!

[Here's the working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03gvnqnh/34/)

The only things wrong with the fiddle you had were:

1) You were referring to `this` when defining the recipes in your controller. ONLY refer to `this` when you are using the `controller as` syntax. Look above for further details.

2) You had a syntax error - you had `};)` instead of `});`

Other than that, your logic and AngularJS structure is fine, so nothing big :)

Let me know if something is still wrong!

Comment: you have correct point that OP should not  either both `controllerAs` and `$scope`, Though OP code should have work..

Comment: I changed deleteRecipe(recipe.id) to urCtrl.deleteRecipe(recipe.id), and after I click the button, nothing happen, no console message appeared. So I changed $scope in my controller to vm(which is equal to this), and I got undefined again.@Ted

Comment: @tina are you sure vm is equal to this? Becuase in your latest version, you removed the `var vm = this`. (I'm not doubting you, I just want to make sure :)   )

Comment: @Ted Yes. I only delete var vm=this here, because that line would make people confused.

Comment: @tina okay makes sense :) as others have mentioned, it looks like it'd be very beneficial for us if you created a plunkr or fiddle

Comment: @tina Updated! Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: @Ted Thank you~ It worked~ I really need to throughly look at that article you mentioned. ;) ;) ;)

Answer (score 0):

When using controller as, you could just put that method on the controller:

```
var UserRecipeController = function($scope, likeRecipesFactory, recipesFactory, appSettings) {

    this.deleteRecipe = function(data){
        console.log("this is recipe: ", data);
    };

    function init() {
        ....
    };

    init();
};
```

then in your html

```
<button ng-click="urCtrl.deleteRecipe(recipe.id)">Delete</button>
```

I don't think it's causing your issue but you may want to wrap that button in a TD tag as you may get some unexpected layout issues.

```
<td><button ng-click="urCtrl.deleteRecipe(recipe.id)">Delete</button></td>
```

Also, it's probably not causing your issue either, but as others have suggested, you probably want to pass the whole "recipe".

```
<td><button ng-click="urCtrl.deleteRecipe(recipe)">Delete</button></td>
```

The reason is that, your HTML shouldn't really need to know anything about how your controller goes about deleting a recipe. For example, the way you have it, if you were to hypothetically change your application such that the recipe had a delete() method on it, you would have to change your view and your controller. If you pass the whole recipe, your view would not need any changes.

Comment: I changed view and controller action as you suggested, and I still got undefined. And you are absolutly right about pass back whole recipe object and not just id part, I changed recipe.id to recipe, and I still got undefined. Thank you for your suggestion.@mcgraghix

Comment: I think we would all need to see a working fiddle or plunkr in order to be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using ng-click="$parent.deleteRecipe(recipe.id)".

Comment: I have tried $parent, but I still got undefined...Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

try replacing

```
function init() {

        ....

      $scope.deleteRecipe = function(data){
        console.log("this is recipe: ", data);
      };
    };

    init();
```

with

```
var 
function init() {

}
init();
$scope.deleteRecipe = function(data){
    console.log("this is recipe: ", data);
};
```

or

```
$scope.init = function init(){
   return {
       deleteRecipe : function(id){ return data;}

   };
}
```

and use it as

```
 ng-click="init.deleteRecipe(id)"
```

Comment: 1st thing OP is using `controllerAs` pattern, he shouldn't be mixing `$scope` in a controller. it wouldn't make any change by changing to what you have suggested.. Though the code OP has should work

Comment: I just tried, and I still got undefined. Thank you.